# 7-8" Tablet for Turtlebot?

Tags: ros, usb, ubuntu, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking to replace the bulky laptop on my roomba-based Turtlebot with a tablet that has a full-size USB port, so that I can do telepresence audio/video with the same machine that does all the mapping & bot/ROS logic. I've been fiddling with a TW700 that I got really cheap, and it's *almost* working, but it has a lot of landmines. Oh, and I might have just bricked it.

Any suggestions for tablets that will run Ubuntu, with good device support, and have a full USB port?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219948/7-8%22-tablet-for-turtlebot?/) by [FarrisGoldstein](https://answers.ros.org/users/24545/farrisgoldstein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm in the same boat as you--we need a lightweight tablet that can run Ubuntu 14.04.3 and ROS indigo and preferably a full-size USB port.

After doing a lot of research I think we have narrowed it down to used Microsoft Surface Pro 1 or 2 tablets or Dell's low-quality 2-in-1 Inspiron 11 3157 (that has terrific battery life and is Ubuntu-certified).

If you are willing to step up from 7-8" to 10" or 11.6", those may work for you. The Surface Pro 1 is actually fairly small. There is some word that the Dell Venue 8 Pro can run Ubuntu but I have not found the full foolproof instructions to do so.

---

Originally posted by [dchang0](https://answers.ros.org/users/25414/dchang0/) with karma: 187 on 2016-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0